# CoreData _NSIsNSSet EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS - crash on app launch

Tags: ios, core-data

We are getting this crash on multiple devices but cannot figure out where it originates from. The main thread is crashing.

Stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x193dfd58c object_getMethodImplementation + 20
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1940f6928 _NSIsNSSet + 40
2  CoreFoundation                 0x193fc2c04 -[NSMutableSet unionSet:] + 112
3  CoreData                       0x198abe014 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willReadWithContents:] + 668
4  CoreData                       0x198ae4280 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet count] + 32
5  CoreData                       0x198be1bb4 __107-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 360
6  CoreData                       0x198be2e70 internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 104
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x193d8b5ac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x193d9843c _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 96
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x193d8b5ac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x193d977d4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 832
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1940648d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
12 CoreFoundation                 0x19405f58c __CFRunLoopRun + 1692
13 CoreFoundation                 0x19405ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
14 GraphicsServices               0x19e4475cc GSEventRunModal + 164
15 UIKitCore                      0x198211744 UIApplicationMain + 1936
16 My App                         0x100b37324 main + 16 (main.m:16)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x193edb384 start + 4
```

At the same time, a background thread operating in a PrivateQueue ManagedObjectContext is busy accessing a ManagedObject via `awakeFromFetch`, stack trace of this thread:

```
NSManagedObjectContext 0x28066c700
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b09617e4 __ulock_wait + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b081bf48 _dlock_wait + 56
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b081bcf4 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 56
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b0828618 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 336
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b0828204 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 144
5  CoreData                       0x1b56686cc _perform + 200
6  CoreData                       0x1b558e2c4 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 156
7  CoreData                       0x1b555033c -[NSFaultHandler retainedFulfillAggregateFaultForObject:andRelationship:withContext:] + 428
8  CoreData                       0x1b554df10 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willReadWithContents:] + 408
9  CoreData                       0x1b55ea5bc -[_NSFaultingMutableSet allObjects] + 32
10 My App                          0x1044fdc3c PSUser.isAdmin.getter + 286 (PSUser.swift:286)
11 My App                          0x1044fdb04 @objc PSUser.isAdmin.getter + 4309900036 (<compiler-generated>:4309900036)
12 My App                          0x1044fc694 PSUser.initCurrentTeam() + 212 (PSUser.swift:212)
13 My App                          0x1044fcbc0 @objc PSUser.initCurrentTeam() + 4309896128 (<compiler-generated>:4309896128)
14 My App                          0x1044fc658 @objc PSUser.awakeFromFetch() + 4309894744 (<compiler-generated>:4309894744)
15 CoreData                       0x1b56520e4 _PFFaultHandlerFulfillFault + 3168
16 CoreData                       0x1b5650ab0 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 908
17 CoreData                       0x1b56527fc _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 260
18 CoreData                       0x1b5666a2c _pvfk_header + 120
19 CoreData                       0x1b5663218 _sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 32
20 My App                          0x10438918c +[PSAppSettings isAutoPilotAllowed:] + 97 (PSAppSettings.m:97)
21 My App                          0x1043fbb9c LocationTracker.updateTrackingState(user:) + 1120 (LocationTracker.swift:1120)
22 My App                          0x104413b4c partial apply for closure #1 in LocationTracker.store(filteredLocations:) + 1275 (LocationTracker.swift:1275)
23 My App                          0x1043bae3c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4308577852 (<compiler-generated>:4308577852)
24 CoreData                       0x1b566b650 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 164
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b081b5ac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b0821a64 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 568
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b0822498 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 400
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b082ba5c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 584
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b0881718 _pthread_wqthread + 276
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b08879c8 start_wqthread + 8
```

I am not certain if the two stacks are related, or if the background thread is dispatching anything to the main thread (why should it?), but the call `newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error` does appear in both stack traces.

The method for `awakeFromFetch` is initializing a calculated object property `currentTeam` via the `initCurrentTeam()` method. This method accesses the `teams` relationship on that object. Here is the relevant code:

```
@objc extension PSUser {

    override open func awakeFromFetch() {
        super.awakeFromFetch()
        initCurrentTeam()
    }
    
    /**
     This method sets the currentTeam by picking 
     the appropriate team from the `teams` set.
     */
    func initCurrentTeam() {
        if (isAdmin || isManager), !isEmployee,
            var teams = teams?.allObjects as? [PSTeam],
            currentTeam == nil {
            ...
            currentTeam = teams.first
        }
    }
    
...
}
```

Enabled com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug in Xcode Scheme but Xcode console does not complain. I have not been able to reproduce this issue while debugging in Xcode. The issue is only reported via Crashlytics in production environment.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Are there any other messages in Xcode's console when this happens?

Comment: I found more info in the stack traces and have edited the question. I hope it can clarify a few things.

Comment: OK then are you saying that there are no other messages in Xcode's console? Because those are usually extremely helpful.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this issue while debugging in Xcode, even with `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` enabled. There are no messages in the console.